# How to group count values into ranges like exactly one, 2 to 5, more than 5

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, range

I have a table of transactions with the concept of sender and receiver which can send transactions:

[image: Transaction table with data]

Now I want to get a result set that should include a range of number of unique senders per receiver:

- one receiver receives from 1 sender
- one receiver receives from 2-5 senders
- one receiver receives from 6-10 senders
- one receiver receives from 11-20 senders
- one receiver receives to over 20 senders

[image: Required final display of data from transactions table]

I have tried but was not able to get required result set. Can any one please help me in this.

Comment: You can use select receiver, count(distinct sender) ....
Please note that pictures are not very helpful and you should provide good samples as text and the desired output.

Comment: @CetinBasoz how i will get a receiver which has just one sender? If i can figure out this, other quries will have similar pattern.

Comment: I've removed the various version tags here (one of which is a version that's has had no support for over 2 years). Tagging the version you are using it useful, but I *doubt* you're using all 3 of those simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a (virtual) table that stores the ranges, then join it with the aggregate data:

```
SELECT ranges.*, COUNT(*) AS ReceiversInRange --, other aggregates
FROM (VALUES
    (1,  1,  1, 'Low risk'),
    (2,  2,  5, 'Low risk'),
    (3,  6, 10, 'Medium risk'),
    (4, 11, 20, 'Medium-high'),
    (5, 20, NULL, 'High risk')
) AS ranges(id, lb, ub, label)
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Sender) AS SenderCount --, other aggregates
    FROM t
    GROUP BY Receiver 
) AS aggdata ON SenderCount >= lb AND (SenderCount <= ub OR ub IS NULL)
GROUP BY id, lb, ub, label
```

Answer (score 2):

This would be a mess as a comment. You didn't really provide sample data and desired output to start with (I don't accept pictures as sample). Anyway, what you are describing is a simple count():

```
select receiver, count(distinct sender) senderCount
from myTable
group by receiver
order by count(distinct sender);
```

would do it. Putting the result into buckets like 1, 2-5, ... could be done in different ways. ie:

```
with counts(receiver, senderCount) as
(
    select receiver, count(distinct sender)
    from myTable
    group by receiver
)
select receiver,
    case 
      when senderCount = 1 then '1'
      when senderCount > 1 and senderCount <= 5 then '2-5'
      when senderCount > 5 and senderCount <= 10 then '6-10'
      when senderCount > 10 and senderCount <= 20 then '11-20'
      when senderCount > 20 then 'Over 20'
    end as individualGroup
from counts;
```

Comment: You also need to group by the same `case` expression

Comment: @SalmanA, which case expression are you talking about? I don't see such a column (I don't see a table structure anyway but deducting from first picture).

Comment: It will return data such as `1, 2-5, 2-5, 11-20` (4 rows) and OP wants it aggregated `1: 1, 2-5: 2, 11-20: 1` (3 rows)

Comment: @SalmanA, are you sure of it? Where is that stated?

Comment: Thanks a lot @CetinBasoz, after looking into the discussion on your answer, I got the Idea and solved the issue. Sorry for not explaining it properly